# How to launch Chrome in Selenium correctly

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

I can not launch Chrome in Selenium.

```
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

  File "/usr/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 67, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)

  File "/usr/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 87, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)

  File "/usr/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 141, in start_session
    'desiredCapabilities': desired_capabilities,
  File "/usr/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 201, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)

  File "/usr/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 181, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506092 (733a02544d189eeb751fe0d7ddca79a0ee28cce4),platform=Linux 3.19.8-100.fc20.x86_64 x86_64)
```

I use "chromedriver_linux64.zip 2017-10-03 21:09:52 3.90MB" from 
[url](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.33/).

Comment: did you unzipped the chromedriver_linux64.zip ?

Comment: @Manmohan_singh of course!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use an old version of Chrome - you will need to match the version of chromedriver to it.  In your case you are using Chrome 38, which was last officially supported by [ChromeDriver 2.13](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.13/notes.txt), which you can find [here](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.13/)

If your users are using newer versions of Chrome, I would recommend updating your distro and installed chrome to match them.

Answer (score 6):

You are using the current latest `chromedriver 2.33` with `Google Chrome 38.0.2125.104`.

From the [release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.33/notes.txt), the support for this version is:

```
----------ChromeDriver v2.33 (2017-10-03)----------
Supports Chrome v60-62
```

Make sure also that you are using the latest stable version of selenium.

Furthermore, from [Help WebDriver find the downloaded ChromeDriver executable](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started), you should do one of these

1. include the ChromeDriver location in your PATH environment variable
2. (Python only) include the path to ChromeDriver when instantiating webdriver.Chrome (see sample below)

Comment: I can launch Chrome via `driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable')`. But after a while,   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 61, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/service.py", line 88, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path) + "'")
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the 'google-chrome-stable'

Answer (score 1):

The error says it all :

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
```

Seems the error occurs on the very first line which is as :

```
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
```

This is because here in this code block unless you import `webdriver`, the `driver` object is unable to properly initiate/handle the instance of `WebBrowser` i.e. **`Chrome Browser`**.

### Solution :

While working with **`Selenium 3.x`**, **`ChromeDriver 2.33.x`** you need `Chrome Browser v60-62` with `Python 3.x` bindings, and you have to do the following:

- Download the `chromedriver` binary from [this link](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/).
- Import the necessary modules
- Provide the absolute path of the `chromedriver` binary in your system.
- Below is the minimal code :

---

```
    //The Linux Example
    from selenium import webdriver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'/usr/bin/chromedriver')
    driver.get('https://www.google.co.in')
    print("Page Title is : %s" %driver.title)
    driver.quit()
```

---

```
    //The Windows Example
    from selenium import webdriver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get('https://www.google.co.in')
    print("Page Title is : %s" %driver.title)
    driver.quit()
```

---

### Update :

On a separate note as you are seeing **`WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed`** perform the following additional steps :

- Uninstall **`Google Chrome`** from your system through **`Revo Uninstaller`**.
- Run **`CCleaner`** to wipe out all the unwanted **`OS`** chores.
- Take a **`system Reboot`**
- Install latest official build of **`Google Chrome`**
- Execute your **`Test`**.

Answer (score 0):

import the selenium and chrome.option to let chrom run in headlessmode

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
```

if you use chrome or chromiun as root user on linux you should add "--no-sandbox" option and set windows size to avoid some item no show because the window size is too small

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless") # headless mode
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox") # run as root user should add --no-sandbox option
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
```

you can download the chrome driver from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com the last version is [2.38](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE)

```
chrome_driver = "path to chromedriver"
# start the driver 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path=chrome_driver)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation in the answer :)

Comment: i install chromium by **apt-get install chromium-browser**